# db2, how to get parent and child records with select query from same table

Tags: db2

Can you give me an idea, how to get parent and child hierarchical data of the same table?

I have a table like this :

```
create table t7(wonum int, parent int, woid int);
```

MY data is like::

```
insert into t7(wonum ,parent, woid )
values(1024 ,   null,      101),
(1025 ,   1024,      102),
(1028 ,   null,      186),
(1029 ,   1028,      157),
(1042,    1024,      123),
(1035 ,   1024,      103),
(1030 ,   null,      122),
(1031 ,   null,      108),
(1032 ,   null,      186),
(1034 ,   1028,      157),
(1035,    null,      123),
(1036 ,   1030,      103)
```

how can I get a result table like this::

```
wonum   parent  woid
1024    null    101
1025    1024    102
1042    1024    123
1035    1024    103
1028    null    186
1029    1028    157
1034    1028    197
1030    null    122
1036    1030    143
1031    null    108
1032    null    156
1035    null    153
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Look into recursive SQL, common table expression (CTE). Come back with your (almost) working query and share the SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

I got this with simple Coalesce() and order by clause.
select wonum, Coalesce(parent,wonum) from t7 order by Coalesce(parent,wonum);